# Otter - text rendering not works

Tags: c#, rendering, sfml, text-rendering, sfml.net

I made method,that draws text using Otter(2D Game Rendering Library using SFML.NET).But method not works correct,text not rendered.
Code:

```
    public static void DrawText(string Text,string Font,int Size,VXG_Color 
                                                                         clr)
    {
        Text t = new Text(Text,Font,Size);
        t.Color = VXGColor(clr);
        t.Render(0f,0f);
        t.Visible = true;
    }
```

Using method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   DrawText("hello", @"C:\Users\serge\Downloads\DarkDemo\DarkDemo\bin\kongtext.ttf", 72, Rendering.VXG_Color.Orange);
 }
```

Method is executed,exceptions not throwed,but its not renders,i dont see text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a answer.
Text class not rendering,because its not added to scene.
To add it to scene,we need to create an entity,and add Text component to it.

```
Game g = new Game();
g.Color = Color.Black;
Scene scn = new Scene();
Text t = new Text("Text","Font",16);
Entity ent = new Entity();
ent.AddGraphics(t);
scn.Add(ent);
g.Start(scn);
```